# Flutter container bottom-center aligned in a stack not fully aligned at the bottom?

Tags: flutter, dart

Please see the code example and screenshot below.  I've got a 300x300 window (the yellow container) where I want to have a status bar at the bottom, but the status bar sometimes has a single pixel at the bottom showing the yellow background (circled in red below).

This doesn't always happen, it's dependent on the size of the window size of the browser.  You have to resize the browser window to see it happen (and not happen).  It seems like its happening about 50% of the time.  My guess is its a rounding error in the Flutter SDK.

Anyone else experience this or know of a work around?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                  height: 300,
                  width: 300,
                  child: Stack(children: [
                    Container(color: Colors.yellow),
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: SizedBox(
                            height: 50,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                            )))
                  ])),
            )));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the height of the window when you are facing this issue ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy - It occurs at various sizes.  In the attached pic the window size returned from using MediaQuery.of(context).size is 562x425.

Comment: Reported to Flutter: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82578

Answer (score 1):

That is really strange! This should yield your desired behavior, though I'd recommend opening an issue in the Flutter repo as this is definitely just a workaround.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(color: Colors.yellow),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: -1,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 51,
                    width: 300,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I found that this still leaves yellow on the sides when resizing the window, the following just uses a column instead of a stack. Not sure if it'll work for your use case but it avoids the issue entirely:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  height: 250,
                  width: 300,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 300,
                  color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Column works for this example, *BUT* how I'm using this in real life, I have video in the window with the bottom bar semi-transparent.  So you can see through the bottom bar to see the video.  If I use a column the video will end where the bottom bar begins, which is now what I want :(

Comment: @TerenceD Totally understand, definitely an interesting problem you have here. Hopefully, someone is able to solve it!